# Do global variables work in Heroku app

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, request, cheerio

I have an app that scrapes from a website and displays it on mine. It works fine locally but on heroku, it does not work. I was wondering if it maybe has to do with having a global array defined in my controller/routes file. I am using 'request' and 'cheerio' to scrape. Once I get the data, I store the objects into my empty global array and then redirect back to my homepage, where I make another object to hold the scraped article array and then display it onto my handlebars.

```
var scrapeResults = [];

router.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.redirect('/home');
});

router.get('/home', function(req, res){
    if(scrapeResults.length > 0){

        var stuff = {
            moreStuff: scrapeResults,
            arrLength: scrapeResults.length,
            finishScrape: true

        }
        res.render('home', stuff)
    }else{
        res.render('home');
    }
});

router.get('/scrape', function(req, response){

    request('http://www.gamespot.com/', function(err, res, html){

        var $ = cheerio.load(html);
        var articleCounter = 1;

        $('article a').each(function(i, element){

            var articleID = articleCounter;
            var title = $(this).attr('data-event-title');
            var link = $(this).attr('href');
            var img = $(this).children('figure').children('div.media-img').children('img').attr('src');
            var description = $(this).children('div.media-body').children('p.media-deck').text();

            scrapeResults.push({
                articleID: articleID,
                title: title,
                link: link,
                img: img,
                description: description
            });

            articleCounter++;

        });
    response.redirect('/home')
    });


});
```

Comment: yes. Running something in a VM is no difference than running it on your own machine (for the most part)

Comment: What do you mean by "it does not work"? Node running on your machine or Heroku will treat JavaScript the same way. Differences only have to do with machine environment, external libraries, etc. So what error are you getting?

Comment: It just wont scrape articles from the target website and display it onto mine. It will work locally but not on heroku